# How to do logging in Spring boot for different log level in different files

Tags: java, api, spring-boot, spring-mvc, logging

I am new to spring boot and want to log different log levels to different files.

Is that possible, if yes please let me know what properties i need to define in application.properties file.

I have researched through some spring boot tutorials and could not find any solution for the same.

Please share links that could help me .

so expected result would be

1. INFO level to  go to a file in specific format like . 
   somefilename_Info_dd/mm/yy_hh:mm:ss.

same with other log levels.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not create your own logger, if you want it completely and 100% configurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For many loggers try to use for example logback:

https://springframework.guru/using-logback-spring-boot/

These are different logging levels and its order from maximum to minimum:

```
TRACE - DEBUG - INFO -  WARN - ERROR
```

If you setup TRACE, it will log everything, if INFO, it will log INFO, WARN and ERROR.

You can read more on:

https://logback.qos.ch/manual/architecture.html